# Odoo 8 - How to create a button that contains a pop-up message with a refresh of the actual view?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-view

I have a button, and I would like to implement a behavior that, when the user clicks on this button, a pop-up message appears with a refresh of the actual view.

I already have the refresh behavior, but I don't know how to create the pop-up message and how to implement it with the refresh.

Comment: Have you created a model and a XML view for your pop-up and you do not know how to get from your button to them or did I understand wrong?

Comment: I don't created neither model and XML view for my pop-up message.
I don't know how to exactly implement the pop-up message beside button and the refresh view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create the popup message you can assign a confirm attribute.

```xml
 <button name="toggle_active" type="object" confirm="(Un)archiving a forum automatically (un)archives its posts. Do you want to proceed?" class="oe_stat_button" icon="fa-archive">
```

This will prompt the user with a confirm dialog which you can use to convey your message and then after they click 'ok' it will execute your action.

```xml
<button name="test_dialog_then_action" type="object" class="oe_stat_button" icon="fa-check">
```

PYTHON Function

```py
@api.multi
def test_dialog_then_action(self):
    return {
        'type':'ir.action.act_client',
        'tag': 'show_my_dialog'
    }
```

JS Script

```js
odoo.define('addon_name.my_dialog', function(require){
"user strict";

var core = require('web.core');
var session = require('web.session');

var qweb = core.qweb;
var mixins = core.mixins;
var Widget = require('web.Widget');
var Model = require('web.Model');
var Dialog = require('web.Dialog');

function ActionShowDialog(parent, action){
    var dialog = new Dialog(document.body, {
        title: "Dialog Title", 
        subtitle: "This is a subtitle!",
        size: 'medium',
        $content: "<div id='my_div'>Hello World!</div>",
        buttons: []
    });
    dialog.open();
    setTimeout(function(){
        dialog.close();
        new Model('your_addon.model_name')
        .call('func_name',arguments)
    }, 3000);   
}

    core.action_registry.add("show_my_dialog", ActionShowDialog);
});
```

Comment: Do you know if it's still possible with this approach but without the `confirm` attribute (which force the user to click on `ok`) ? Just to show the pop-up while the action still continue ?

Comment: I dont think so. I think some of the other methods for displaying a popup will halt script execution. Another option is to connect your method to an function which returns a client action which displays a Dialog built via javascript. And then after a timeout the javascript triggers the original function you are planning to execute. This will be a lot more work but its an option.

Comment: Do you know a StackOverflow's thread or another forum's thread that already talked about what you said in your comment ?

Comment: Not that I know of. Most people use confirm attribute. It takes 2 seconds and its not pretty but the alternative takes a great deal longer. I have done it and I think it would still take me an hour to organise the code. Odoo's javascript api is complicated and if you have not worked with it then doing something like this will be difficult unless you have a strong js background.

Comment: I will post something for you.

Comment: You will have to add the js to the backend assets and add more functionality to call the action method you intend to call when closing the dialog.

Comment: Thanks for all this informations @PhillipStack ! I will test this method as soon as I can.

Comment: I come back to you @PhillipStack, to have more information about your J.S code. In your code, you specify some strings like `addon_name`, `your_addon`, `model_name`, `func_name`. What are these strings exactly ? Are they named like this as a guide or do they refer to my Odoo module ?

Comment: They are to be replaced by the name of your module and model names. They are simply "hello world" placeholders.

Comment: Does `func_name` must also be replaced @PhillipStack? I think yes but I don't know with what...

Comment: It actually does not have to be replaced. You probably should but it will have no bearing on whether or not it works or not. Again, a hello world placeholder.

Comment: When I added the J.S function to the Odoo's assets backend, and I called this function in Odoo side, I got this type of error :`Odoo : TypeError: viewclass is not a constructor`

Comment: What version of odoo are you running?

Comment: Odoo 8, as it said in my title

Comment: Oh yes. Sorry about that. I will update my answer, it would only work for Odoo9 and above. My mistake.